# Error after migrating database from SQL Server CE to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration, sql-server-ce

I have used the migration feature in WebMatrix to migrate my .sdf database to SQL Server. I am now getting the error below:

```
var usernameExists = db.Query("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = ?", username);
```

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '?'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +2073502

Do I need to add code to indicate which Database to open? Will I now need to change the syntax for all my database queries? Sorry, I am new to SQL Server and am finding it very difficult to find any resources for migrating using WebMatrix and what I need to do to get my application fixed and working fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `?` to `@0`. Different database providers use different placeholders for parameters. The SqlClient one uses @parametername syntax.